# Power BI Drill through feature not filtering the matrix table

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to use the drill through feature in Power BI. I have two reports. I have added my fields into the drill through section for my second page. When the user right clicks on an item and drills through it does show 'Page 2'. It also shows the filters correctly but for some reason it doesnt actually filter the matrix table. It still shows all.

The filter section shows all the filters with (All) next to it. The drill through shows the correctly filtered one ticked. But the actual matrix table still shows All. When I click the filter button of my matrix visualisation it does show its being filtered but it looks like the table is not refreshing properly!

Any ideas?

Comment: If the field in the field belongs to a table different of the one used in the matrix, then check the relationships between the table. You are probably missing one in the designer.

Comment: do you ignore filters in the matrix measures?